# Instead of insert trigger not executing if statement corectly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a trigger on my database which prevents a specific user from entering and stops a user from entering the same question twice:

```
create trigger [dbo].[question]
on [dbo].[Online_Questions]
instead of insert
as
if SYSTEM_USER = 'John'
begin 
raiserror('You have not paid up your fee',16,1)
rollback transaction
end
if exists(select 1
    from Online_Questions a, inserted b where a.UserName = b.UserName 
     and a.Question_ID = b.Question_ID)
begin
raiserror('You have already submitted this question',16,1)
rollback
end
go
```

It successfully prevents John from entering, but it stops anyone from entering twice regardless of the Question_ID.

For example:

```
execute as login = 'Tom';

insert into Online_Questions (UserName, Question_ID, Answer)
values (user, 'Q097', 'D');
```

and then

```
insert into Online_Questions (UserName, Question_ID, Answer)
values (user, 'Q087', 'D');
```

would return an error as the trigger has prevented the insert.

I don't see why this is as the if statement checks for both the existence of username and the question_ID?

Any suggestions?

Comment: try to change this trigger for a after trigger, I have a problem like this a few weeks ago but i cannot remeber exactly was the problem. As you are using a rollback inside the statment so will not be a problem a after trigger.

Comment: @FpontoDesenv I have to use an insert trigger (it is a requirement) so unfortunately I can't try an after trigger

Comment: @AaronBertrand I thought I was already looking at this when I was matching up the values being inserted to those already in the table?

Comment: Erm, why not just have a unique constraint on `Username, Question_ID`? (I missed the `inserted` in your `exists` check because you're using ugly old-style join syntax instead of proper `ANSI` joins, and meaningless aliases like `a` and `b` - why not `oq` and `i`, for example?) Why does the if exists check return four columns instead of just *, NULL or 1? Having more of the query on the screen (or using carriage returns a little more liberally) makes it much easier for others to spot everything that's there without having to scroll all over the place.

Comment: Finally, did you actually check the data? You have `user` in your `VALUES()` clause. Do you know what that returns? For me, it's `dbo` (run `SELECT user;`). So it's quite possible you are filling up your table with `dbo` or some common username for every single user on your system.

Comment: One more thing, why doesn't the trigger have an eventual insert statement? It's called `instead of`, not `before`, for a reason - you have to perform the insert that the trigger has trumped. So is the symptom that you are getting an error, or that the row isn't getting into the table?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I was aware of the `User` in my values. It was done that way to automatically insert the user who was running the statement. You'll notice I'm using `execute as` to substitute their log in and effectively run the query as them.
I may not have done everything right up to scratch, I'm still new to SQL programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out where I was going wrong, it wasn't quite properly formatted and looking at both tables. Here is the solution.

```
create trigger [dbo].[question]
on [dbo].[Online_Questions]
instead of insert
as
if SYSTEM_USER = 'John'
begin 
raiserror('You have not paid up your fee',16,1)
return
end
if (not exists (select oq.UserName, oq.Question_ID from Online_Questions oq, inserted i where oq.UserName = i.UserName and oq.Question_ID = i.Question_ID))
begin
insert into Online_Questions
select User, Question_ID, Answer
from inserted
end
else
begin
raiserror('You have already submitted this question',16,1)
end
go
```